# After using Firefox User Agent Switcher to emulate iPhone, Google now always thinks I'm on an iphone

Tags: firefox-addon, user-agent

I switched to the iPhone user agent during which time I visited Google, then I changed back to the default Firefox one again. I cleared all of my history, cache and cookies but Google still thinks I am on a mobile device and insists on directing me to the mobile site. I have checked my user agent and it is definitely the correct one and I have removed every single cookie in Firefox.

How is Google remembering this information? Is there some other sort of mechanism apart from cookies that remembers user settings? It doesn't do it in any other browser.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some issues such as this on Firefox.  Which add-on are you using to change the UA?

To be absolutely sure what the UA String you can [Check you User Agent String](http://www.myuseragentstring.com/)

Also you can check for cookies using the [Fire Cookie Add-On](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firecookie/)

Normally i can fix this issue by **Closing** the web browser and starting up a new instance of Firefox.

My other issue with Firefox is that it caches HTTP redirection rules from a website, so if i change a HTTP redirection rule on the server Firefox does not immediately pick this up - This problem is also fixed by closing the web browser.

Comment: I'm not particular bothered any more, as I just set the home page to http://www.google.co.uk/webhp? instead of http://www.google.co.uk/ but even after completely formatting my PC, if I do go the root of Google, it still displays the mobile version. This is with no plugins.

Comment: You can try going to www.google.com/ncr - NCR stands for No Content Redirect. See if that works

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in firefox by resetting my default agent:

```
Tools->Default User Agent->Default User Agent
```

and then going to:

```
Tools->Clear Recent History->Cache
```